# Installing react-reveal issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, installation, reveal.js

I wnat to install react-reveal to my project so I can deploy it safelly with beautifull animation.

I tried to add react-reveal to my local project with react. after executing the command: `npm install react-reveal` it prompts me this message:

```
npm ERR! While resolving: myportfolio@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-reveal@1.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-reveal
npm ERR!   react-reveal@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\hpsim\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-05T21_01_20_702Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\hpsim\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-05T21_01_20_702Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried to force installl it, it works localy but when I tried to push it to my github, then Netlify tells me me that it's impossible to deploy my project.
How can I fix this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: React-reveal apparently can only operate on version 15 or 16 of React, so if you want to use the library you need to downgrade React. Maybe try another library, the last merged request to the repo was 6 years ago.